# solr how to handle trademark sign and value

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I am able to convert the helloWorld® to helloWorld using HTMLStripFieldUpdateProcessorFactory , but when data is like "helloWorld&+reg" [ I have put + symbol in between as it was converting it to ® sign] ,HTMLStripFieldUpdateProcessorFactory  is not able to parse it to helloWorld .
one way I can use patternReplacement but I do not want to use this for each individual  case , example for © and its corresponding value again I will have to write a pattern Replacement  .

can I use anything else which will handle the value of trademark symbol ?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to keep? A-Z0-9? Spaces?

Comment: if I have a word helloWorld&+reg" , I want to keep helloWorld , that i am also able to do when it comes like helloWorld® , but not able to parse it when its helloWorld&+reg" [ I have put + symbol in between as it was converting it to ® sign]

Comment: But what about spaces? Numbers? Any special characters? Is there any reason why a negative match in a PatternReplaceCharFilter wouldn't work? `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` as the pattern and `""` as the replacement.

Comment: spaces and numbers i am taking care , the only problem with trademark values , PatternReplaceCharFilter  would work. but for this i would need to put pattern for each trademark value

Comment: So you only want to remove a few explicit values? In that case, you'll have to add those values specifically.